# MongoDb db.collection.find() With Special Character

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to write a simple query in MongoDb using PyMongo driver as such

```
mongo.db.people.find_one({'name': 'Tést Name'})
mongo.db.people.find_one({'name': 'Test_O%27Name'})
```

Both of these queries are returning null. I have checked to make sure the data exists in the db. How do I change the query so that find() is able to find it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do only exact match with special characters, or do you want to be able to have `Test Name` match an entry with or without specials?

Comment: Can we see the sample data you are trying to match?  The first find you have would seem to be valid: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uW9wX8lT96X

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /.*\$tes.*/i });
```

You have to escape $ by :